# How to detect if coordinate is inside region?

Tags: java, kotlin, coordinates

I am trying to detect if a player is inside a specific region, I currently store a `Region` object that contains two variables that I'll be calling `cornerOne` and `cornerTwo`, the corners are basically vector variables that contains X, Y, Z, I save all the regions on a [`MutableSet`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-set/index.html).

I want to make sure that the new vector I am passing to it is inside the region.
Currently what I tried was:

```
fun isInRegion(location: Location): Boolean {
    return regions.none { inside(location, it.cornerOne, it.cornerTwo) }
}

private fun inside(location: Location, cornerOne: Location, cornerTwo: Location): Boolean {
    return (location.x >= cornerOne.x && location.x <= cornerTwo.x) && 
           (location.z >= cornerOne.z && location.z <= cornerTwo.z)
}
```

I am ignoring Y because the region is only horizontal, so I'll be ignoring height.
The way I currently have it, works for the first 3 regions, but as soon as I make a 4th one it stops working completely, detects the first ones but doesn't the other ones.
Is there a better way to do this? I was told a quadtree could be better, but I don't understand how it would work in this situation.

PS: I am tagging Java too because if someone sees it in the Java section I won't mind a Java help either.

**Edit:**
On the region code I have `if (!isValidRegion()) return` which will prevent the region from being too small:

```
fun isValidRegion(): Boolean {
    return !(getXSelected() < 5 || getZSelected() < 5)
}
```

This makes sure that `cornerOne.x <= cornerTwo.x` and `cornerOne.z <= cornerTwo.z`.

This is the method to get the selected X, it'll get the X of the final block and subtract from the X of the first block.

```
private fun getXSelected(): Int {
    return abs(finalBlock.x - originBlock.x) + 1
}
```

**Edit 2:**
So I changed the `inside` function to be:

```
private fun inside(location: Location, cornerOne: Location, cornerTwo: Location): Boolean {
    return inBetween(location.x, cornerOne.x, cornerTwo.x) && 
           inBetween(location.z, cornerOne.z, cornerTwo.z)
}

private fun inBetween(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int): Boolean {
    return (a in b..c) || (a in c..b)
}
```

And it worked, however I don't know if this would be a good solution, as I don't know if it would be bad for performance if it is called too often.

Comment: show the code and the data you're using to run through these functions and try to show how exactly they fail. We need to be able to reproduce your behaviour if we are to help you. Also, consider making encompassing classes for your objects, something called BoundingBox or something to handle the overlapping logic. Also take a look at existing solutions like https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/mapsforge-core/src/main/java/org/mapsforge/core/model/BoundingBox.java

Comment: Wouldn't you want `regions.any` instead of `regions.none`? I.e. check if `location` is inside any of the boxes, rather than outside all of them?

Comment: Make sure you always ensure `cornerOne.x` <= `cornerTwo.x` and  `cornerOne.z` <=  `cornerTwo.z`

Comment: @Tschallacka I'll add a bit more info in a second.
@Thomas You're right, I was actually using `regions.none` then negating it on return, I copied it wrong I forgot to add the `!`, but yeah `any` would be better for sure.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev That is ensured in the region creation code, it cannot be less than `5 x 5`

Comment: @User12322341232142 add the code that ensures that, because I have the feeling that this might be your issue

Comment: @BorisStrandjev I edited with the code to check if the Region is `5 x 5` I am sure this part works.

Comment: @User12322341232142 I am just trying to cover all potential causes. For the moment I still do not see enough of this generation. Can we see the `getXSelected()` method?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev There you go, that is all there is to it. However, I think I am finally understanding the problem here. I think the problem is that I am checking `location.x >= cornerOne.x && location.x <= cornerTwo.x` but I am not checking if it is the way around, if `location.x >= cornerTwo.x && location.x <= corneOne.x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code in one of two ways:

1) change the definition of `inside` to be (less preferred):

```
private fun inside(location: Location, cornerOne: Location, cornerTwo: Location): Boolean {
    return (location.x >= Math.min(cornerOne.x, cornerTwo.x) && location.x <= Math.max(cornerOne.x, cornerTwo.x)) && 
           (location.z >= Math.min(cornerOne.z, cornerTwo.z) && location.z <= Math.max(cornerOne.z, cornerTwo.z))
}
```

Or change the way you generate `cornerOne` and `cornerTwo`:

2.1) do without the `abs in your generation (you will need more iterations of generation)

2.2) after you generate the initial candidates of corners swap `cornerOne` xs if their order is not as expected and do the same on the z axis (separately!!)

Comment: So, I edited the post with a solution I found, do you think that would be a bad idea?
Also wouldn't removing the abs from the generation make it so it could be -5 x 5, which would break the check no?

Comment: @User12322341232142 kotlin ranges should not work downwards counting. Isn't your code failing with exception? Overall my aim was to ensure that cornerOne is lower left and corner two is upper right upon creation so that you would not need to worry about comparison later on. Removing abs should not affect the size of the square, just ensure that the second x is definitely bigger than the first (rather than the distance between the two being at least 5 in any direction)